# Bootstrap navbar not collapsing when run as Wordpress theme

Tags: html, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I had a working static HTML site using Bootstrap and a collapsing navbar, but when I split it to turn it into a Wordpress theme, the design is fine, the only thing that doesn't work fine is the navbar when in the mobile viewport. The navbar will open to show the links but it won't collapse again, and it stuck open.

Putting the code inside header.php into a normal HTML file renders the navbar fine.

header.php

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Bootstrap + dependencies -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- style -->
    <link href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/style.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- Image and text -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: I turned your code into an executable snippet and as you can see, it works exactly as expected. What you need to post is this: [mcve]

Comment: I agree with you that it works when run with plain HTML/CSS, but when the snippet is taken and put into a WordPress header.html file, the navbar will open, but it won't close again when pressing the navbar-toggler.

Comment: So, something must be different in the output there. The output will be the same "plain" HTML/CSS. Find out what's different.

Comment: @WebDevBooster I copied the contents of the header.php file to a blank index.html and index.php file - both files functioned correctly. However the issue arises when I replace header.php with the working index.php file - the header displays correctly on all the pages but won't close once it has been opened. There is no difference between the code in the working in index.php and the code that doesn't work in header.php.